# Changed Keyboard layout and now can't login anymore because letters are missing on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

as you can see from the title i once changed my keybord layout into turkish
using this command on the terminal

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

The terminal said, i should restart the machine, so that the changes would get applied.This i did only to realize, that i cannot login anymore, because some german letters are not included in the turkish keyboard layout.

Comment: Better to post the answer separately and then accept that, but this isn't really a programming Q useful for StackOverflow. Posting to Superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i solved this, was as following. 
I created an Ubuntu-Live-Usb with the Laptop of my girlfriend, thats really easy to do on windows.

Than i used chroot to mount the ubuntu on my laptop, to the Live-USB.
After that i cd'd into the home directory of the mounted ubuntu and there deployed the same terminal command

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

to get it back to the german Layout.